# How to execute SQL queries in parallel in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have 3 SQL queries running as below, currently I am running each of them sequentially consuming time, I want to explore the option to run them in parallel in C#. I would like to know is there any such possibility in C#? Is it even doable?

```
sql1 = select DISTINCT A.Name 
       from masterdata.Areas as A,
            ...................
       and SPB.SoftwareProductBuild = 'build1'

sql1 = select DISTINCT A.Name 
       from masterdata.Areas as A,
        ...................
        and SPB.SoftwareProductBuild = 'build2'

sql1 = select DISTINCT A.Name 
       from masterdata.Areas as A,
        ...................
       and SPB.SoftwareProductBuild = 'build3'

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql1, odsConn);

SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
rdr.Read();

if (rdr.HasRows)
{
}

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql2, odsConn);
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

rdr.Read();

if (rdr.HasRows)
{
}

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql3, odsConn);

SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
rdr.Read();

if (rdr.HasRows)
{
}
```

Comment: Use threads maybe

Comment: Use async await, that's the only and best solution

Comment: As far as I can tell, parallel queries depend on the database server. Even if your application sends the queries simultaneously to the database server, it decides on how to execute them.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - Does aysncwait help to execute queries in parallel?do you have any pointers to how to use it?

Comment: @afaolek - My database server does allow to execute simultaneously

Comment: @afaolek what you are saying will create a difference when queries are submitted to the database server, here they are submitted sequentially, which will change with Async Await, as they are submitted in parallel

Comment: As far as I understand your question, You have 3 different queries which returns "Name" as output based on "SoftwareProductBuild" column filter in where condition. I suggest that, Make one store procedure that contains all the three queries and return output. In code side, you catch its result in dataset. So in Dataset you can get every result as single Datatable. By this way, Its decrease the load of simultaneously request on server and get better performance.

Comment: @DipakDelvadiya What you are suggesting is using MARS (multiple active result set), which again is sequential execution in database, but its single network call, that's the only advantage

Answer (score 0):

Do it as a `UNION` or `WHERE SPB.SoftwareProductBuild IN ('build1', 'build2','build3')` and let the database sort it out.
More efficient use of connections, networks, brain power and probably CPUs too.